# Error with request to the server: unexpected response from server

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

I have a SharePoint 2013 on-premises site and I have owner access on it.
There is a requirement to create a customized forms using HTML and CSS for which we are using content editor web parts for which the HTML file is being referred from Site Assets gallery but when we change anything in HTML file or any file in that matter and try to upload it again to Site Assets it gives an error saying "Error with request to the server: unexpected response from server., StackTrace:".
Please find the screenshot attached for better understanding of the error,
[image]

Comment: Did you check the ULS log entries ? try using IE.

Comment: Try drag'n'drop file using IE or install SPGO extension for visual studio code >  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SiteGo.spgo

Comment: Thank you Karthik and Marko for the response, it worked in IE browser, but why is it creating issues in Chrome? any suggestion...

Comment: Try refreshing the page before uploading the document. If the request digest of the page is expired, it also does not allow to upload anything or doing post request in general

Comment: Thank you everyone for helping me out to fix this, really appreciate..The issue seems to be fixed, checked the server quota, server usage and load on the server but everything was pretty normal.. There was McAfee security installed in the system which was restricting the site to respond, I have uninstalled the software and it seems to be working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

There are currently multiple issues with Chrome and SharePoint due to the recent changes in Chrome behavior. There is currently no fix for it from MS.

Please see this knowledge base article. 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/troubleshoot/miscellaneous/chrome-behavior-affects-applications